# What is the significance of 3DD in Pirahana 3DD?

Tags: title, pirhana-3dd

What is the significance of 3DD in the movie title [Piranha 3DD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_3DD). Is this the lack of new title or any other meaning inside it. Is there any official word on it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bit of a play on words/abbreviations.  The first part, 3D, was for the intention for the movie to be viewed in 3D.  The second part, DD (pronounced Double Dee) is a reference to the bra size that some women wear.  This is because there are a lot of scantly clad women in the movie, it happening in the water and women wearing bathing suits and all.

Also, the second D is also an indicaiton that it's the second movie.  The first movie was called "Pirahana 3D", adding the second D alludes to it being a sequel.